# Schubert cycles on Grassmannian bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, intersection-theory, chern-classes

Let $X$ be smooth variety and let $\mathcal{E}$ be a vector bundle on $X$ of rank $n$. On the total space of the Grassmannian bundle $\pi:G(k,\mathcal{E})\to X$ we have the tautological exact sequence $0\to\mathcal{V}\to\pi^{*}\mathcal{E}\to\mathcal{Q}$, and the Chow ring of $G(k,\mathcal{E})$ is generated over $A^{*}(X)$ by the Chern classes of $\mathcal{V}$ with relations coming from $c_{l}(\mathcal{Q})=0$ for $l>n-k$.

Suppose now that $\mathcal{E}$ has a full flag of subbundles $0=\mathcal{E}_0\subset \mathcal{E}_1\subset\cdots\subset\mathcal{E}_n=\mathcal{E}$. Then, one can define Schubert cycles in the relative setting; by Leray-Hirsch they generate the Chow ring of $G(k,\mathcal{E})$ additively over $A^{*}(X)$.

Questions:

1. Is there a Littlewood-Richardson rule for these Schubert cycles, presumably involving the Chern classes of the $\mathcal{E}_i$?
2. Are there explicit formulas for the Schubert cycles in terms of the Chern classes of $\mathcal{V}$ and the $\mathcal{E}_i$?

I am guessing the answers are in the literature somewhere, but I haven't been able them written down.

Comment: See the  book by  Laurent Manivel *Symmetriv Functions, Schubert Calculus and Degeneracy Loci*.  In Sec. 3.5 you will find the description of Chern classes as special Schubert cycles. Schubert calculus describes the intersection ring o Grassmannians. In particular it describes a Schubert  cycle as a polynomial in the Chern classes, Giambelli formula, (Corollary 3.2.10 in the above reference).

Comment: The reference you gave seems to treat the standard story of Schubert cycles on Grassmannians, but my question concerns relative Schubert cycles on Grassmannian bundles.